# PowerShell Function - Validate Required PSSession

Tags: function, validation, powershell, parameters

I'm attempting to validate that a specific PSSession has been established and is active before allowing a PS function to be run.  Unfortunately it looks like ValidateScript doesn't fire unless you provide input, setting the default value won't fire ValidateScript either.

Is there a way to validate that a specific PSSession exists before Begin/Process/End fires?  If not I'm assuming I'll need to put this logic into the function itself.

I don't want the user to have to provide the expected PSSession as an argument, I'd prefer the function automatically validate it before running.  Below is an example of what I was trying to accomplish.

```
function Get-O365License
{
    <#
    .Synopsis
       Short description
    .DESCRIPTION
       Long description
    .EXAMPLE
       Example of how to use this cmdlet
    .EXAMPLE
       Another example of how to use this cmdlet
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param
    (
        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Position=0)]
        $Identity,

        # Param2 help description
        #[Parameter(DontShow)]
        [ValidateScript({Get-PSSession})]
        $MsolSession,

        # Param2 help description
        #[Parameter(DontShow)]
        [ValidateScript({Get-PSSession})]
        $EXOSession
    )

    Begin
    {
    }
    Process
    {
    }
    End
    {
    }
}
```

The reason I want to validate specific sessions have been run before this function runs is so I know all the requirements of the function are in place.

For example if I try to run Get-MsolUser in the function before running Get-MsolService then the function will fail with the following error:

```
Get-MsolCompanyInformation : You must call the Connect-MsolService cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-MsolCompanyInformation
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Get-MsolCompanyInformation], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.MicrosoftOnlineException,Microsoft.Online.Adm
   inistration.Automation.GetCompanyInformation
```

Likewise if I try to call Exchange remote PowerShell functions without connecting to Exchange first the commands won't be available.

Comment: It's not pretty but you can perform validation on an unrelated arg.

[ValidateScript({
            if ($_ -like "" -or $_ -like $null) {
                throw "`-Identity is a required parameter."
            }
            else {
                $exchange = Get-PSSession
                $msol = Get-PSSession

                if (!$exchange -or !$msol) {
                    throw "Connection to MSOl and Exchange Online is required, check your active PSSessions."
                }
                else {
                    return $true
                }
            }
        })]